# practical example of keyword parameters with core.typed

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

Following the [wiki](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed/wiki/Types)  of `core.typed` about keyword parameters, I came up with the following code snippet to test it. I don't see why I am getting the error below.

```
(ns typeddemo
  (:require [clojure.core.typed :as t]))


(t/ann testfn (Fn [Any & :mandatory {:a t/Num :b t/Num} -> t/Num]
                  [Any & :optional  {:a t/Num :b t/Num} -> t/Str]))

(defn testfn
  [y & {:keys [a b]}]
  (if (and (number? a) (number? b))
    (+ a b)
    "Missing b"))

(testfn 55 :a 5 :b 6)

Static method clojure.lang.Numbers/add could not be applied to arguments:


Domains:
    java.lang.Long java.lang.Long
    java.lang.Double java.lang.Double
    t/AnyInteger t/AnyInteger
    java.lang.Number java.lang.Number

Arguments:
    (t/U Number nil) Number

Ranges:
    java.lang.Long
    java.lang.Double
    t/AnyInteger
    java.lang.Number

with expected type:
    t/Str

in: (clojure.lang.Numbers/add a b)
```

I had expected that `core.typed` can infer that when the test `(and (number? a) (number? b))` passes, then both arguments must be `t/Num` and therefore the result should also be `t/Num`. Only when the test fails, the type is `t/Str`. Why does it claim that the `add` function is not applicable. How can the arguments be `(t/U Number nil) Number` given the condition?

Comment: This looks like a bug in occurrence typing. I assume this happens with just the `[Any & :mandatory {:a t/Num :b t/Num} -> t/Num]` arity?

Comment: Strange, this actually works when I replace Fn with IFn

   `(defn testfn
     [y & {:keys [a b]}]
     (if (and (number? a) (number? b))
       (+ a b)
       "Missing b"))

   (t/cf   (t/ann testfn (t/IFn [t/Any & :mandatory {:a t/Num :b t/Num} -> t/Num]
                                [t/Any & :optional  {:a t/Num :b t/Num} -> t/Str])))

   (t/cf (testfn 55 :a 5 ))`